# Cannot prove that there are Words in my list for my WordSearch game

Tags: python

I have created a list of all possible outcomes for this specific wordgrid, doing diagonals,up,down and all the reverses too):

I have called this `allWords`, but when I try too find specific words I know are in the `allWords` the loop does not find the Hidden words. I know my problem but I do know how to go around it (sorry for terrible explanation hopefully an example below will show it better):

an Example follows: My `wordList` is the list of words that I know are hidden somewhere in the wordgrid. My `allWords` is a list of Rows,Columns,Diagonals from the wordgrid but

```
WordList = ['HAMMER','....']

allWords = ['ARBHAMMERTYU','...']
```

that `HAMMER` is in `allWords` but 'cloaked' by other characters after it so I am unable to show `HAMMER` is in the wordgrid.

```
length = len(allWords)
for i in range(length):
    word = allWords[i]
    if word in wordList:
        print("I have found", word)
```

it does not find any word `HAMMER` in `allWords`.

Any help towards solving this problem would be great

Comment: Can't understand your english. Basically, what you are trying to achieve?  if every element of `WordList` exists in any element of `allWords`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to find a match inside allWords and you want to iterate over WordList and determine if there is a substring match.

So, if that is correct, then your code is not exactly doing that. To go through your code step by step to correct what is happening:

```
length = len(allWords)
for i in range(length):
```

What you want to do above is not necessarily go over your allWords. You want to iterate over WordList and see if it is inside allWords. You are not doing that, instead you want to do this:

```
length = len(WordList)
for i in range(length):
```

With that in mind, that means now you want to reference WordList and not allWords, so you want to now change this:

```
word = allWords[i]
```

to this:

```
word = WordList[i]
```

Finally, here comes a new bit of information to determine if you in fact have a substring match in the strings you are matching. A method called "any". The "any" method works by returning True if at least one match of what you are looking for is found. It looks like this:

```
any(if "something" in word in word for words)
```

Then it will return True if it "something" is in word otherwise it will return False.

So, to put this all together, and run your code with your sample input, we get:

```
WordList = ['HAMMER','....']

allWords = ['ARBHAMMERTYU','...']

length = len(WordList)
for i in range(length):
    word = WordList[i]
    if any(word in w for w in allWords):
        print("I have found", word)
```

Output:

```
I have found HAMMER
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing each `word` in `wordList` to a word in `allWords`. The line `if word in wordList` compares the exact word.
i.e.

`if word in wordList` will return True only if the word **Hammer** is in `wordList`.

To match substring you need another loop:

```
for i in range(length):
    word = allWords[i]
    for w in WordList:
        if w in word:
            print("I have found ", word)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
for word in allWords:
    if word in WordList:
        print("I have found", word)
```

Ah, or maybe the error is that you wrote wordList and you really defined WordList. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you probably need to implement a function that checks if a token (e.g. `'HAMMER'`) is present in any of the entries in `allWords`. My best bet for solution would be to use regular expressions.

```
import re

def findWordInWordList(word, allWords):
    pattern = re.compile(".*%s.*" % word)
    for item in allWords:
        match = pattern.search(item)
        if match:
            return match
```

This will return first occurence, if you want more then it's easy to collect them in a list.